# unable to install mysql server on ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, updates, software-installation, software-center

the error I encountered while updating in ubuntu 11.10. since I found that ubuntu 11.10 supports much better than 12.04 for matlab, I have rebooted my OS to ubuntu 11.10. And even here, I face same problem. I feel this must be a trouble from oneiric

```
sudo apt-get update    
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates InRelease                     
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports InRelease                   
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed InRelease                    
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                           
Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg                   
Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-backports Release.gpg                 
Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease                                 
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-proposed Release.gpg                  
Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg                               
Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security InRelease                      
Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release.gpg                    
Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-proposed/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-proposed/Release.gpg     Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg         Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release.gpg           Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg         Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.177 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release amd64 (20111012)]/ dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release amd64 (20111012)]/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main restricted #Added by software-properties

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric restricted main multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates restricted main multiverse           #Added by software-properties

deb http:// in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security restricted main multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-proposed restricted main multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-proposed restricted    main multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Comment: which sql server are you trying to install?

Comment: in order to help, could you paste what error you encountered and could you write down what you have done exactly? The command prompt you entered e.g ... Did you tried to install mysql server? Or do you wanted to install Oracle 11g?

Comment: I want to install mysql server. the error I face is //   [sudo] password for karishma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server//

Comment: I can see the error: it is the `InRelease` part of the URLs, what I cannot see is where it comes from, `sources.list` looks ok to my eyes.

Comment: So is there something that I can try for...

Comment: thank you for the help you extended from your side....I will try to find some solution

Comment: It looks like in.archive.ubuntu.com has some problems, I ran into similar errors right now. Please try to change to another download server, for instance the "main" server archive.ubuntu.com. I am trying to see if there a possibly **several** problems we are fighting.

Comment: even that didn't work out

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server requires Microsoft Windows OS to run. There is no way you can install SQL Server on Ubuntu.  It can only happen using some form of VM.

Make sure that you have Important security updates checked.

[image]

To install MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade   
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This will install just MySQL 5.5

[image]
[image]

To install Apache2 With PHP5 And MySQL Support On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

<sup>Source: Thanks to Shankar Raman</sup>

Comment: I was trying to install through that method.  I confront this error.              [sudo] password for karishma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server

Comment: Look at the additions in my answer.  I just tried it that way it was, and it worked.  Try the command before the install command.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: when I am typing for update and upgrade, I get so many failed executions with last line,"0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded." Moreover adding "sudo apt-get install mysql-server" command resulted in "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server"  Should I download somepackage or something?

Comment: See additions in my answer.  Also make sure that you Internet connectivity is OK.

Comment: my internet connectivity is fine, and the option you were telling was already ticked. Still I couldn't make it. I was browsing through net, and they were asking to select install option in software center. But even I don't have that option in software center.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Oneric (11.10) has been end of life for a very very long time, and the repositories no longer exist for it on http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

12.04 is the earliest version with decent support life left. 10.04 still has a couple of months of support for the server version, but i'd recommend 12.04 or 14.04 if you can use either of those.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated already, Ubuntu Oneric is EOL, so its official repositories are no longer mantained. But if you wish to keep using the no-longer-updated official repositories you can change your current (no more available, and that's the cause of the error) repositories to those hosted on [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/) by running the following command; it will update your current `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use the non-longer-updated repositories:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup && sed 's/http:\/\/.*\.ubuntu\.com/http:\/\/old-releases\.ubuntu\.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list.backup | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And after this you can run `sudo apt-get update` to update the `apt` cache followed by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` to install `mysql-server`.

---

**Command breakdown:**

- `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`: renames `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.backup`
- `sed 's/http:\/\/.*\.ubuntu\.com/http:\/\/old-releases\.ubuntu\.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`: replaces any string starting with `http://` and ending with `.ubuntu.com` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com` within `/etc/apt/sources.list.backup`
- `sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list`: ouputs everything to `/etc/apt/sources.list`