# Issues installing MySQL server on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: apt, mysql

I'm currently trying to install a MySQL server on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine. The problem is, when I try to install it, I get error messages indicating that not all packages could be downloaded. When I run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, and after hanging for a while at reading headers, the console reads as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,077 kB/24.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried the suggested fix or running apt-get update and such, I've made sure I have no connections blocked, I've restarted, uninstalled, reinstalled, etc, all to no avail. I've been searching the web all day for solutions I haven't yet tried, but most people with this issue are running an older version of Ubuntu. (By the way, I did try the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302742/unable-to-install-mysql-server-on-ubuntu)) Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any proxies that the request goes through? What is the output of `ping -c 5 91.189.92.190`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then try `sudo apt-get install -f` and see if you can install `mysql-server`.